# SQL Pivot Table isn't working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot, unpivot

SQL 2005

I have a temp table:

```
 Year         PercentMale   PercentFemale  PercentHmlss   PercentEmployed  TotalSrvd
 2008           100                0           0              100              1
 2009           55                40           0               80             20
 2010           64                35           0               67            162
 2011           69                27           0               34            285
 2012           56                43          10                1             58
```

and I want to create a query to display the data like this:

```
                    2008    2009    2010    2011    2012
 PercentMale         100     55      64      69      56 
 PercentFemale        -      40      35      27      43 
 PercentHmlss         -      -       -       -       10 
 PercentEmployed     100     80      67      34      1 
 TotalSrvd            1      20     162     285      58
```

Can I use a pivot table to accomplish this? If so, how? I've tried using a pivot but have found no success.

```
 select PercentHmlss,PercentMale,Percentfemale,
     PercentEmployed,[2008],[2009],[2010],[2011],[2012] from 

 (select PercentHmlss,PercentMale, Percentfemale, PercentEmployed,
     TotalSrvd,year from @TempTable)as T

  pivot (sum (TotalSrvd) for year 
     in ([2008],[2009],[2010],[2011],[2012])) as pvt
```

This is the result:

```
 PercentHmlss   PercentMale     Percentfemale PercentEmployed [2008]  [2009]    [2010]      [2011]   [2012]
    0               55              40            80           NULL     20      NULL         NULL     NULL
    0               64              35            67           NULL    NULL     162            NULL  NULL
    0               69              27            34           NULL    NULL     NULL          285     NULL
    0              100               0           100             1     NULL     NULL         NULL    NULL
   10               56              43             1           NULL    NULL     NULL         NULL     58
```

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is.  `No success` isn't a description.  Did you get error messages?  *(You appear to be missing a `,` in the middle of `PercentEmployed[2008]` for example.)  Or did you get data, just not the data you expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work you will want to perform an [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and then a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT *
from
(
  select year, quantity, type
  from 
  (
    select year, percentmale, percentfemale, percenthmlss, percentemployed, totalsrvd
    from t
  ) x
  UNPIVOT 
  (
    quantity for type
    in 
    ([percentmale]
     , [percentfemale]
     , [percenthmlss]
     , [percentemployed]
     , [totalsrvd])
  ) u
) x1
pivot
(
  sum(quantity)
  for Year in ([2008], [2009], [2010], [2011], [2012])
) p
```

See a [SQL Fiddle with a Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce488/8)

Edit Further explanation:

You were close with your PIVOT query that you tried, in that you got the data for the `Year` in the column format that you wanted.  However, since you want the data that was contained in the columns initially `percentmale`, `percentfemale`, etc in the row of data - you need to unpivot the data first.

Basically, what you are doing is taking the original data and placing it all in rows based on the year.  The UNPIVOT is going to place your data in the format ([Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce488/10)):

```
Year    Quantity    Type
2008    100         percentmale
2008    0           percentfemale
etc
```

Once you have transformed the data into this format, then you can perform the PIVOT to get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks Bluefeet. I don't quite understand how it works... but it works! I'll study it and try to figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Stan see my edit with additional info on `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`

Comment: One thing I don't understand, how does the code make it so the number values are QUANTITY and TYPE are the field names? I played with the code in Fiddle and noticed that Quantity and Type are not keywords, it doesn't appear as though where they are placed in the Select statement has an effect. What am I missing? Thanks again.

Comment: @Stan I just picked those names, you can call them anything for those fields. You just have to specify a name for the columns that you want to unpivot.